# Using objective c files in swift project without using use_frameworks flag

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2, cocoapods

I use this [SDK](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk) which does not have dynamic frameworks and I can't simply use this flag `use_frameworks!` to achieve quick using objective c files in my swift project.

What should I do to use that objective c files received from cocoa pods in my Swift project?

Do I need to make bridging and if so how to actually do it?

Comment: If you don't have `use_frameworks!` in your podfile, you will have to add bridging header to your project. Anyway, what error did you got when you declare `use_framework!` in your podfile?

Comment: @HoaParis if I use that flag I get this [!] The 'Pods-QuickBloxIntegrationGiude' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/amatrosov/Desktop/QuickBloxIntegrationGiude/Pods/QuickBlox/Quickblox.framework)

Comment: It seems that CocoaPods does not manage this case by mixing non-dynamic & dynamic frameworks. I don't know if it's possible or not. I suggest to import your SDK into project manually to avoid this problem.

Comment: @HoaParis, as I need to do then it manually right to bridge all files. I assume that if I will drag and drop library it will allow me automatically bridge all headers. am I right?

Comment: after drag-drop the library, you have to indicate the header search path in your project setting. Then, in your bridging header file, import the main header (.h) file of that library.

Comment: @HoaParis, qb team answered to me on github, I've added an answer. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to use it we can simple follow this guide:
http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#Additional_steps_for_Swift_using_CocoaPods

qb team provided with me.